# Remover CSS dentro do iframe

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

Olá, tenho uma página e estou exibindo ela em um iframe, quero criar como se fosse uma versão 2 da página com outro estilo, pra isso quero remover o css dela e adicionar outro sem ter que editar no arquivo style.css, pois também quero manter a página v1 com o mesmo estilo.
Me ajudem, está no mesmo domínio.

Comment: Vc pode criar um outro css apenas para a outra página.

Comment: Vc não está entendendo, quero editar o que está dentro do iframe e conservar a outra página, além disso eu quero remover algumas divs

Comment: Vc quer alterar estilos e manipular elementos.

Comment: Sim, quero editar os estilos e remover uma div chamada topo, onde fica o menu e a barra de pesquisa

Comment: Postei uma resposta com o codigo necessario para isso. Essa div "topo" tem id?

Comment: Tá sem id infelizmente

Comment: Tudo bem, não precisa ter id, mas tem que ter alguma referência.

Comment: Só faltou uma pequena correção no código, que vou atualizar agora.

Comment: Tem o name que é topo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode acessar os elementos do `iframe` usando, por exemplo, a `id` do `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="frame" width="500" height="200" src="pagina.php"></iframe>

<script>
    var iFrame = document.body.querySelector("#frame");

    iFrame.onload = function(){ // aguarda o iframe ser carregado
        // altera a cor do texto da #div1 dentro do iframe
        iFrame.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#div1").style.color = "red";
    }
</script>
```

Usando `iFrame.contentWindow` você pode acessar os elementos com `querySelector` ou outra forma de selecionar elementos que quiser.